# Linq to return summed values from differing datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have the following code :-

```
        var distinctValues = DtSet.Tables["tblData"].AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(row => new
                    {
                        name_1 = "1",
                        name_2 = "I",
                        name_3 = row.Field<string>("EorD"),
                        name_4 = row.Field<string>("InvNo")
                    })
                    .Distinct();
```

If I have another datatable (DtSet.Tables["tblCost"]) with 2 columns, "InvNo" and "Amount", how can I add a fifth column to my first piece of code to bring back the sum of the amounts for each InvNo on tblCost? Like :-

```
        var distinctValues = DtSet.Tables["tblData"].AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(row => new
                    {
                        name_1 = "1",
                        name_2 = "I",
                        name_3 = row.Field<string>("EorD"),
                        name_4 = row.Field<string>("InvNo")
                        name_5 = **Summed total of Amount column on tblCost per InvNo**
                    })
                    .Distinct();
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I can't really wrap my head around your relationships. It seems that you want to calculate a sum for a *collection* of InvNo's but one row in tblData corresponds to only one invoice number. Either way, you should create a view, or a join query to join the two tables you have together. Once you have the joined table or view, you can do a Sum query on the amounts.

Comment: tblcost has many instances of each InvNo. tblData only has one. I would like the sum of the amounts for each corresponding InvNo as found on tblCost, displayed in tblData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a "group join" and do it in one query:

```
var distinctValues = 
    (from data in DtSet.Tables["tblData"].AsEnumerable()
     join cost in DtSet.Tables["tblCost"].AsEnumerable().Where(r=>!r.IsNull("Amount"))
        on data.Field<string>("InvNo") equals cost.Field<string>("InvNo") 
            into dc
    select new
    {
        name_1 = "1",
        name_2 = "I",
        name_3 = data.Field<string>("EorD"),
        name_4 = data.Field<string>("InvNo"),
        name_5 = dc.Sum(d=>d.Field<int>("Amount"))
    })
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: This is close! However, there are null values in the Amount column, and this could be causing the "Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Decimal'. Please use a nullable type." error I'm getting. Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Incredible! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Perform a query in SQL that joins the two tables and sums the ammount

```
SELECT
    D.EorD,
    D.InvNo,
    SUM(C.Amount) As TotalAmount
FROM
    tblData D
    LEFT JOIN tblCost C
        ON D.InvNo = C.InvNo
GROUP BY
    D.EorD, D.InvNo;
```

I used a left join in case there is no corresponding record in tblCost.

Note: I'm not sure about the column `EorD`. I assume that `InvNo` is unique in `tblData`. Otherwise you should either inlude it in the join if there is a corresponding column in `tblCost` or remove it from the `GROUP BY` and apply an aggregate function on it like `MAX(D.EorD) AS EorD`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm struggling with the syntax for the Sum. I've tried sum(c.Field<decimal>("Line Value") as TotalAmount, but I am getting a "The name 'sum' does not exist in the current context" error.

Comment: `Sum` has an upper case first letter. (C# is case sensitive.)

Answer (score 0):

You should join your collections, group it and aggregate:

```
        var tblDataValues = DtSet.Tables["tblData"].AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(row => new
                                {
                                    name_1 = "1",
                                    name_2 = "I",
                                    name_3 = row.Field<string>("EorD"),
                                    name_4 = row.Field<string>("InvNo")
                                })
                                .Distinct();;
        var tblCostValues = DtSet.Tables["tblCost"].AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(row => new
                                {
                                    InvNo = row.Field<string>("InvNo"),
                                    Amount = row.Field<int>("Amount"),
                                }
            );


        var joinedValue = tblDataValues.Join(tblCostValues, v => v.name_4, c => c.InvNo, (v, c) => new { c, v })
                .GroupBy(k => k.v, c => c.c)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    g.Key.name_1,
                    g.Key.name_2,
                    g.Key.name_3,
                    g.Key.name_4,
                    name_5 = g.Aggregate(0, (s, c) => s + c.Amount)
                });
```

Comment: I've tried using this, and I'm getting a "'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'name_1' and no extension method 'name_1' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) on each f the g.Key lines at the bottom.